# Can this discrete random variable be rigorously constructed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Sorry for the odd title, but I couldn't think of what to call this. I'll describe the properties of this hypothesized distribution below. I'd like to know if this is a valid probability distribution (and can it be rigorously constructed?)

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable on $\{1,...,n\},n<\infty$. Here are the properties of its probability mass function $P(\cdot)$:

$$P(X=0)=1, P(X=1|X>0) = 1, P(X=2|X>1)=1,...,P(X=k+1|X>k)=1$$

Intuitively, if we let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables, where:

$$X_i \sim P_{X|X>X_{i-1}}$$

Then is seems that $X_i = i,\; a.s.$

Could someone with more theoretical experience than me provide a rigorous construction of this random variable or explain why it fails to be a proper probability distribution?

Comment: If $P(X=0)=1$, then $X$ is constantly $0$, isn't it? It can't ever assume any other values since $P(X\neq 0)=0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MPW the problem is that we are conditioning on zero probability events for $X>0$. I guess I'm imagining that in an infinite sequence of iid rvs with each having this hypothetical distribution (unconditional form), then at most a finite number of these variables will be non-zero.

Comment: @MPW - in other words, I imagine $X^{-1}(c) \subset \Omega$ for any integer $c>0$, its just that these are null sets of the unconditional probability measure.

Comment: @MPW sorry if I am confusing...my interest in this exceeds my formal training...any additional information you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\left(Y_i\right)_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of iid random variables where each $Y_i$ is uniform over $[0,1]$. Now let $$X=n-\left|\{i:Y_i>0\}\right|.$$

Comment: +1. Clever! Ok, so I get that $P(X=0)=1$ and I also see that if $X>1$ implies at least 1 $Y_i$ is 0. Conditional on this, we get $X|X>0 = 1 + (n-1)-\left|\{i:Y_i>0\}\right|$ where $i$ does not include the indices of the zero-valued random variables. Correct?

Comment: OK, i've convinced myself that this construction works....very cool!

Comment: @Bey, yes. That was my reasoning.